# Solaris 11 - (unix: Could not start init) Program terminated)

Tags: solaris, init

During a restart of a server with Solaris 11, the system halted with the following alert:

```
WARNING: exec(/usr/sbin/init) failed with errno 8. (unix: Could not start init) Program terminated.
```

The operating system keeps on reboot and never comes online. Since `init` is one of the first processes to come up we are assuming that we will never be able to log onto the server.

Is there a way that we can log into the system and check what the issue is, and possible resolve it?

Comment: As far as I know, errno 8 is "exec format error", which tells me init might somehow be corrupted. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Yes @schaiba, you're right. errno 8 is in fact an exec format error. However going into the system to check and possible fix that is a bit of a problem.

Comment: Can you try booting from a different media (CD, DVD, bootserver), and check the boot disk? Could be a disk problem. Otherwise, if you manage to get the exact version of Solaris, you could make some diff.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways, but you left off which architecture (SPARC or x86), as well as your boot device configuration (SAN, NAS, disk, mirrored disks, ...).

Agree with ludiegu that you could boot off media to check the state of the rpool.  However, under Solaris 11, with ZFS and BEs, the easiest thing to do would also be to boot from a different BE.

- On [SPARC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/gldpr.html), you could use a combination of booting at the OBB off the dev with -L to determine the BEs, and -Z for the BE/dataset.
- On x86 pick a different BE from GRUB.

From either media or a different BE, issue a scrub on rpool which may require being imported.

And if the drives are mirrored try booting off the alternate boot drive.